# Load ads after page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ads

It'a just a question there is any way to load ads after page..? Something like mediafire

example http://www.mediafire.com/?ohd522ats0qjb8d

im try make some tricks with jquery but dont work :( my ads code looks like this

```
<!-- BEGIN SMOWTION TAG - 728x90 - DO NOT MODIFY -->
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer"><!--
smowtion_size = "728x90";
smowtion_section = "87as8d48aas";
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ads.smowtion.com/ad.js?s=87as8d48aas&z=728x90">
</script>
<!-- END SMOWTION TAG - 728x90 - DO NOT MODIFY -->
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably against someones TOS, but you could probably do:

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript('http://ads.smowtion.com/ad.js?s=87as8d48aas&z=728x90', function() {
       smowtion_size = "728x90";
       smowtion_section = "87as8d48aas";
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for the tos, smowtions a stickler about doing this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

Could you check in firebug console for any error? It might be one of the reason for not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.getScript('http://ads.smowtion.com/ad.js?s=87as8d48aas&z=728x90', function() {
          smowtion_size = "728x90";
          smowtion_section = "87as8d48aas";
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you want to put your add in a div with id=add

```
$(function(){
   $('#add').append('<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
                       smowtion_size = "728x90";
                       smowtion_section = "87as8d48aas";
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.smowtion.com/ad.js?s=87as8d48aas&z=728x90"></script>
                     ');
});
```